# Text and second line is not being displayed with plot() and line()

Tags: r

None of my text is being displayed when I `source` my code in RStudio. Also the second line isn't being displayed. I am not sure why this is happening. my vectors `alphas`, `acc_3`, and `acc_1` all have values within them.

```
alphas = c(0.050, 0.075, 0.100, 0.150, 0.175, 0.200, 0.225, 0.250, 0.275, 0.300)
acc_1 = c(0.9997631, 0.9999210, 0.9995263, 0.9980261, 1.0000000, 0.9996052, 1.0000000, 0.9999210, 1.0000000, 0.9996052)
acc_3 = c(0.9526814, 0.9626709, 0.9563617, 0.9447950, 0.9616193, 0.9600421, 0.9521556, 0.9505783, 0.9490011, 0.9463722)  
plot(alphas, acc_1, type="l", xlab="Alpha", ylab="Acc", col="red")
lines(alphas, acc_3, col="green")
```

[image]

Comment: It's going to be really hard for anyone to help without a fully reproducible example here: we'd need you to provide `alphas`, `acc_1`, etc. so we can run this ourselves.

Comment: @joran updated!

Comment: Ok, so the first call to plot is setting up a plotting region that doesn't include the range for the second set of data. In this circumstance we'd typically do a "dummy" call to plot first with just the min/max and type = "n" as "setup" and the do two `lines()` calls. Or what @zx8754 did; that works too. ;)

Comment: I think you missed the codes for adding texts. Assume it has the same issue as being out of plot y axis range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to set the Y limits, so it includes values for both *acc_1* and *acc_3*:

```
myYlim <- range(c(acc_1, acc_3))

plot(alphas, acc_1, type = "l", xlab = "Alpha", ylab = "Acc", col = "red", ylim = myYlim)
lines(alphas, acc_3, col = "green")
```

[image]

---

Using *matplot* (as suggested by [@thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496803) in the comments):

```
matplot(alphas, cbind(acc_1,acc_3),
        type = "l", lty = 1, col = c("red", "green"), ylab = "value")
```

> Plot the columns of one matrix against the columns of another.

[image]

---

Or using *ggplot*, prepare tidy data, then plot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

plotDat <- data.frame(alphas, acc_1, acc_3) %>% 
  gather(key = "acc", value = "value", -alphas)

ggplot(plotDat, aes(alphas, value, col = acc)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]